# class container full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class

I want my page to be in a `class="container"` but I want the header (the blue and grey column) also in the class but I want the blocks to give the background to the whole row. So the blue and grey color needs to be over the whole width. I was wondering if there is some way to get that?

**The question:**
Is there a way to get the grey and blue block to be the full width so the color is the full width but the text is just like it is now. The div has a `class="container"`

[image: How it looks like]

Comment: yes there is a way but all depend on your code so share it

Comment: What do you mean? the website is just in a `<div class="container"></div>` ?

Comment: we need to see it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

<div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Groepen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Trainingen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Inloggen</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>

  </div>

  <div class="subheader">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="middle-section">
   <div class="container">

   </div>
  </div>
```